# Is it possible to run two programs simultaneously or one after another using a bash or expect script?

Tags: bash, scripting, expect, wireshark, tcpdump

I have basically two lines of code which are:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 65535 -w - >/tmp/Captures

tshark -i /tmp/Captures -T pdml >results.xml
```

if I run them both in separate terminals it works fine.

However I've been trying to create a simple bash script that will execute them at the same time, but have had no luck. Bash script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 65535 -w - >/tmp/Captures &

tshark -i /tmp/Captures -T pdml >results.xml &
```

If anyone could possibly help in getting this to work or getting it to "run tcpdump until a key is pressed, then run tshark. then when a key is pressed again close."

I have only a little bash scripting experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to run tcpdump and tshark separately? Using a pipe command will feed the output of tcpdump to the input of tshark.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 65535 | tshark -T -pdml > results.xml
```

Comment: For that matter, why run `tcpdump` at all? Just allow `tshark` to do the capturing and format the output...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That worked a treat! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Also thanks twalberg for the input, but it is for a little project I am working on and I need to use both tcpdump and tshark. :)